# Homophone generator

Tags: algorithm

Is there an algorithm for generating homophones?

Input "cypress", output = { cipress, cipres, cypres, sipress, sypress }

Comment: +1rep for just saying "homophone"

Comment: Wow I read this question wrong.  Suddely it's not quite as interesting.

Comment: Apple usually release one every couple of years ;)

Comment: They're words that sound the same but mean something different - iPhone, eyePhone, ayePhone aightPhone - these are all homophones

Comment: @stupd-phil most, if not all, of those are not real words

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try It.This Library will generate as you required

```
npm install homophonizer
```

[Homophonizer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/homophonizer)

Answer (score 3):

[Soundex](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soundex) is the reverse of this - mapping homophones to the same value.
If you indexed every word in a dictionary by its Soundex value, then you could do a lookup to find all homophones of a given word.

Answer (score 3):

I made one. Source code here: https://github.com/evanshort73/homophone

Try it out in your browser at http://evanshort.name/homophone/

Basic idea: Download the CMU Pronouncing Dictionary, and create a file of allowed phoneme substitutions and their costs. Do a depth first search of every possible substitution, backtracking when the partial result is not the beginning of any dictionary word.

Answer (score 2):

You might be better off downloading a list of homophones from a web site somewhere.  A quick Google search for "list of homophones" gives a few interesting-looking sites, including http://www.homophone.com.

Comment: `A quick Google search for "list of homophones"` - you were brave :D

Comment: obviously you're not at work if you're searching for "homophone"

Comment: Actually part of my work involves full-text search, an area in which homophones are something of a problem.

Answer (score 2):

There is a (and I quote..) Homophoner *(**stiffled giggle**)* here:
http://yacomink.com/homophoner/

It seems to be using YUI

Comment: The link has died :-(

Comment: @Ponkadoodle updated, took a long long time but nevermind

Answer (score 2):

Project Gutenberg has the [Webster's Unabridged Dictionary](http://www.gutenberg.org/catalog/world/results?title=unabridged+dictionary) available for download.  You could use the pronunciations in the dictionary as a key.  Just parsing the dictionary would be a project unto itself, though.